# MobilePress plugin and WordPress 4.1 update

Tags: plugins, updates, mobile

A client website is currently running on WordPress 4.0.1 and he asked for an update to 4.1.

The website uses the MobilePress plugin, which had problems with WordPress updates in the past, but unfortunately I can't find out much about that.

On the MobilePress's [official plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobilepress/), it says it's compatible up to WordPress 3.6.1 (though it's working on this 4.0.1 installation).

I have some questions:

1. How important is to do the WordPress update?
2. Can I revert the update case something wrong happens?
3. What could eventually break, regarding the MobilePress plugin? And
   how could it be fixed?

**EDIT**

Updated, nothing bad happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to be short:

1. Be up to date is very important. There are a lot of reasons but my "favourite" is security.
2. Make a backup before update, so you can restore the site if something was wrong.
3. What can be broken and how could it be fixed? I can not know, I've never used that plugin and I'm not going to test it for you (sorry, test and fix third party software is not the purpose of this site), but I can advise you to do this: make a mirror site with the exact same set of themes and plugins. Working in the mirror site, enable [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to know if you are using deprecated stuff that can break WordPress in the future. Fix errors if any. Then update. If everything is fine, you are ready to update the live site.